# Compare existing file in two different directories, copy if not existent, else overwrite it

Tags: files, directory, cp, diff

I'm trying to build a scrip that compare a file inside different 2 dir,then
copy them from dir1 to dir2 is it's not exists in the dir2, or overwrite it if its already existed.

I know that i can use `diff dir1 dir2` but then how do copy the result over to dir2. because `diff` command give me result like `only in dir1: file1.txt`, from my understand that isn't a file itself(right?)

For the overwrite part, i decide to use `[ -ot ]` command, but again, from my understand the  `[ -ot ]` only can compare with file but not dir?

Comment: It looks like you're reinventing rsync :-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888012/how-to-rsync-a-single-file

Comment: @JaroslavKucera thanks for reply, but can rsync work with local dir? is it design for some kind of network file transfer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rsync` works locally and does tests on both file timestamps and file sizes.

```
rsync --archive /path/to/source/ /path/to/destination/
```

You may also use `rsync` on individual files.

Comment: `-u` is the right option for timestamps comparison ?

Comment: @PrinPuyakul `-u` will skip files that are newer on the destination end. Without it, `rsync` will transfer all files whose timestamps (or sizes) are *different*.

Comment: I see `-a, --archive` is what i'm looking for, but I just wonder how can I printout the result from rsync after it successfully execute (like a file name) @Kusalananda

Comment: @PrinPuyakul You may use `-v` or `--verbose` to see what it's doing, and `--progress` to see it work on bigger files. `--stats` will give you a summary at the end.

Comment: I did try --archive, but it will copy everything over to a new dir every tho the file has an older timestamp, what did i do wrong  ?_?.
from what I understand it NOT suppose to copy older timestamp file over the new one right?

Comment: @PrinPuyakul Did you also use `-u`? With only `-a`, `rsync` will make sure that the target is _exactly_ as the source. With `-au` it will skip files in the target that are newer than in the source.

Comment: ok, it seem to do what is suppose to do, one last question are there any command in linux that target only the overwrite file, or i need to do it by timestamp. Regards.

Comment: @PrinPuyakul I think you have to explain that a bit more. I don't understand what you mean by "target only the overwrite file".

Comment: for example, i `-rsync` from dir1 to dir2 and it overwrite 2 file in dir2, i'm looking for the way to display only 2 overwrite file that just process by `rsync` , i try like `ls dir2/ -t` it give me everything right and i try to do `find -mtime` but i still can not find any argument that usable for my need

Comment: `rsync -ai src/ dst/ | awk '/^>/ { print $2 }'` would give you a list of files copied to the destination. See the `-i` or `--itemize` option in the manual.

Comment: Billion!!! you are genius !!!  I will study the `awk '/^>/ { print $2 }'` more to understand the syntax =D, really appreciated your explanation and you patient to explain everything again, best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Why not `cp`?

```
\cp -f /path/to/dir1/* /path/to/dir2/
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try bouth `cp` and `rsync` =D